# How are tasks assigned to ForEach iterations

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The Lookup-ForEach pattern is common in Azure Data Factory (ADF). How are items produced by the Lookup allocated to the ForEach's workers, the number of which is controlled by Batch Count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are allocated round-robin, in the order they are produced by the Lookup. Although I can find no documentation to assert this, it is my observation. I can reliably reproduce it with a simple example.

To a new pipeline I added an array variable, a ForEach, and inside the ForEach a Wait (pipeline JSON is included at the end). The array variable feeds the items of the ForEach. Although the question mentions Lookup the result is the same when an array variable is used. The Wait's duration is determined by the array's values, simply to spread the itterations over time to make them more easily observable.

I ran the pipeline and collected the ADF output. I used the Duration to calcualte an End time (shown below in mm:ss). I added three further columns, one for each "worker". To understand which worker executed which itteration I followed the Start-End chains.

```
Task       Start                         Duration  End    A  B  C
========== ============================  ========  =====  =  =  =
9 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:17:39.6100287Z  00:01:32  19:11        c
8 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:17:09.3290518Z  00:01:32  18:41     b
7 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:16:40.6095309Z  00:01:32  18:12  a
6 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:16:07.9623704Z  00:01:32  17:39        c
5 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:15:37.7842636Z  00:01:32  17:09     b
4 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:15:07.9421207Z  00:01:32  16:39  a
3 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:15:06.3028589Z  00:01:02  16:08        c
2 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:15:06.3028589Z  00:00:32  15:38     b
1 Wait1    2021-06-01T05:15:06.2872305Z  00:00:02  15:08  a
  ForEach1 2021-06-01T05:15:05.896518Z   00:04:06
```

I arbitrarily assign Task 1 to worker A. It finished at 15:08 so I find a task that started then (within the precision of the reported durations) which is task 4 and assign it to worker A also, and so on. Tasks 2 and 3 start their own chains similarly. The resulting pattern is that of round-robin allocation.

This analysis on much more complicated workloads, involving many more tasks, larger Batch Counts and varying durations, produces the same evidence for round-robin allocation. For example, serving 21 tasks when Batch Count is 20 I see the 21st task never starts until the 1st one completes.

```
{
    "name": "ForEach RoundRobin Demo",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('Intervals')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "batchCount": 3,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Wait1",
                            "type": "Wait",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "waitTimeInSeconds": {
                                    "value": "@item()",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "Intervals": {
                "type": "Array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    1,
                    30,
                    60,
                    180,
                    180,
                    180,
                    180,
                    180,
                    180
                ]
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: I use Lookups a lot and I think the answer is, it doesn't matter if your ForEach is going to run in parallel, which is the default.  It can spin up to 20 threads in parallel so your process has to be able to run independently.  Make sense?  If your batch process has some sections which must run sequentially (as mine does) then simply force the ForEach to run in Sequential mode in which case the sort order applied to your Lookup applies.

Comment: See here for a similar example I worked up for the `Get Metadata` activity:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070635/1527504

Comment: @wBob Thanks. For clarity - batch count's default is 20, its max is 50.

Comment: Nice! I'm particularly impressed by the stored-procedure-as-sort-utility trick.